# Group by in PIVOT operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

How do i use the group by clause in the PIVOT operator?

[image]

I tried with the following code but i get the null values and the results are not getting aggregated.

```
select  EmpName, CHN,HYD FROM location
PIVOT (Sum(salary)  for EmpLoc in ([CHN], [HYD]))
AS 
pivottable
```

I want the final output to be like this.

```
        CHN HYD
kunder  400 200
shetty  150 150
```

or

```
        CHN HYD Total
kunder  400 200 600
shetty  150 150 300
Total   550 350 900
```

Comment: You could put your pivot in a cte and write a statement with GROUP BY on that one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the derived column  `Total=CHN+HYD`  and a sub-query to create the Total Row

The Seq (though not displayed) will put the Total row at the bottom

```
Declare @YourTable table (EmpLoc varchar(25),EmpName varchar(25),Salary int)
Insert Into @YourTable values
('HYD','kunder',200)
,('HYD','shetty',150)
,('CHN','shetty',150)
,('CHN','kunder',200)
,('CHN','kunder',200)


Select EmpName, CHN,HYD,Total=CHN+HYD
 From ( 
        Select Seq=0,EmpLoc,EmpName,Salary From @YourTable
        Union All
        Select Seq=1,EmpLoc,'Total',Salary From @YourTable
      ) A
   pivot (sum(Salary) for EmpLoc in ([CHN], [HYD])) P
```

Returns

```
EmpName CHN HYD Total
kunder  400 200 600
shetty  150 150 300
Total   550 350 900
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @YourTable table (EmpLoc varchar(25),EmpName varchar(25),Salary int)
Insert Into @YourTable values
('HYD','kunder',200)
,('HYD','shetty',150)
,('CHN','shetty',150)
,('CHN','kunder',200)
,('CHN','kunder',200)


;with cte as
(
SELECT * from 
            (
                select *  from @YourTable
           ) as y
            pivot 
            (
                 sum(salary)
                for EmpLoc in ([CHN], [HYD])
            ) as p
            )
SELECT   
    EmpName,sum(CHN)CHN ,sum(HYD)HYD 

FROM CTE  
GROUP BY EmpName;
```

Comment: What is the `row_number()` for?

Comment: sorry @SqlZim i am removing it

Comment: I am sorry. I get an error.  
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.

Answer (score 0):

I have no issue using your code from your example to get your desired results. I am guessing that your query is not as simple as your example, and as such is introducing other complications not shown here.

You may need to use a subquery and pivot using just the columns necessary for the pivot and join back to the rest of your query to get the results you are looking for using `pivot()`.

Using conditional aggregation may be a simpler solution:

```
select 
    empname
  , CHN = sum(case when emploc = 'CHN' then salary else 0 end)
  , HYD = sum(case when emploc = 'HYD' then salary else 0 end)
  --, Total = sum(salary) /* Optional total */
from location
group by empname
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/LYRH81756

returns:

```
+---------+-----+-----+
| EmpName | CHN | HYD |
+---------+-----+-----+
| kunder  | 400 | 200 |
| shetty  | 150 | 150 |
+---------+-----+-----+
```